# propel setup with symfony2

Tags: symfony, propel

I am new to symfony and I want to use Propel in my project. I have setup the project with symfony2 with composer and want to use propel 1.6. I have kept my propel inside vendor. After adding `$bundles = array(new Propel\PropelBundle\PropelBundle())` it throws error, class is not defined.

I have installed propel from github and follow the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You did only install propel but not the propel-bundle which provides the symfony2-integration.

Add this to your composer.json in order to install propel-bundle:

```
"propel/propel-bundle": "1.2.*@dev"
```

... now propel itself will automatically be downloaded aswell as propel-bundle depends on it.

Now update your dependencies:

```
composer update
```

Afterwards clear your cache:

```
app/console cache:clear
```